# What is a "very low quality" answer?

Tags: discussion

What is a "very low quality" answer?  I flagged [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/vhdl-converting-from-an-integer-type-to-a-std-logic-vector/105234#105234) as very low quality, which was declined with the reason:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

My reasons for flagging it in the first place were:

- it is very late (>3 years) that adds nothing to other answers.
- it should have been a comment.
- it is technically inaccurate, as pointed out by two other correct answers and comments on one other inaccurate answer.

Perhaps I could have flagged as "not an answer", or not flagged at all.

Advice on how I can flag this kind of answer better in future would be useful, as would any examples of when to use "very low quality".

Comment: It's a useless flag; I've raised several on multiple sites and they're always declined. It seems that "not an answer" can always be used in its place.

Comment: My understanding is the flag should be used if the "answer" is complete gibberish or makes no attempt at all to answer the question (a rant on politics, for example). For the issues you point out (technically inaccurate and adds nothing to existing answers), we are supposed to just downvote. For the "could have been a comment" issue, a "not an answer" flag may be justified.

Comment: @ThePhoton but even those examples you gave are good candidates for "not an answer"

Comment: See also [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95581/the-limits-to-a-very-low-quality-answer).  I don't agree with the top answer because it's so personally subjective, but it's interesting reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In his case I declined the flag. Indeed the answer is quite poor, and could have been a comment (although I'm not sure how useful). That's why I left a comment below it.

The reason I declined the flag is that it's an attempt from a new user to participate to the site, and I feel like deletion should be reserved for posts that actually harm the site when left there. I prefer seeing poor answers downvoted, then it's up to the poster to delete them if he/she has a problem with them.

My intention was not to discourage you from flagging posts, just to give *my* feedback about what *I* consider worth flagging. I'm also open to your (and I mean anyone's) feedback on this.

Looking for reference, I've found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123382/should-i-flag-a-poor-comment-of-a-poor-answer). And [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167632/177507) (from a SE.Team's member ;)) pretty much explains my vision.

Comment: Cool, I don't mind either way.  If I'm going to flag then it might as well be useful, so advice for the future is worthwhile.

Comment: Also I assume that the "flags should not be used for technical inaccuracies" is policy on StackOverflow which could be adopted here if chosen, rather than enforced at all times.